# Can't figure out this PHP script

Tags: php, database, pagination, row

I'm a PHP novice, and I recently found this database-free pagination script on a forum; however, I can't quite understand which part of the script defines a row (or item), and how many rows a page can have before a new page is created for overflow. Can someone help me out?

```
<?php
class display {
function pagination($rows, $per_page, $current_page, $page_link) {
    global $core,$C;

    // Create a Page Listing
    $this->pages = ceil(10 * $rows / $per_page);

    // If there's only one page, return now and don't bother
    if($this->pages == 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Pagination Prefix
            $output .= "<!-- Pagination by Dennis Pedrie. Used by Permission -->";
    $output = "Pages: ";

    // Should we show the FIRST PAGE link?
    if($current_page > 2) {
        $output .= "<a href=\"". $page_link ."?page=1/\" title=\"First Page\">&lt;&lt;</a>";
    }

    // Should we show the PREVIOUS PAGE link?
    if($current_page > 1) {
        $previous_page = $current_page - 1;
        $output .= " <a href=\"". $page_link .">page=". $previous_page ."/\" title=\"Previous Page\">&lt;</a>";
    }

    // Current Page Number
    $output .= "<strong>[ ". $current_page ." ]</strong>";

    // Should we show the NEXT PAGE link?
    if($current_page < $this->pages) {
        $next_page = $current_page + 1;
        $output .= "<a href=\"". $page_link ."?page=". $next_page ."/\" title=\"Next Page\">&gt</a>";
    }

    // Should we show the LAST PAGE link?
    if($current_page < $this->pages - 1) {
        $output .= " <a href=\"". $page_link ."?page=". $this->pages ."/\" title=\"Last Page\">&gt;&gt</a>";
    }

    // Return the output.
    return $output;
}
}
$display = new display;
echo $display->pagination("45", "15", "1", "http://theapplenewsreel.com/news/index.php");
?>
```

Comment: try this tutorial for pagination: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $display->pagination("45", "15", "1", "http://theapplenewsreel.com/news/index.php");
```

pass the number of rows you wish to have in the first parameter, and how many per pages in the second parameter

Comment: But are these regular, HTML table rows, or something else?

Comment: what your displaying out are links. I strictly recommend you to go through php tutorials . And if your so keen in knowing pagination visit http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: But the thing about this script is that it works without a db. The net tuts link you've included, as most on the internet, require MySQL, where my host provides terrible MySQL support.